# React router loading route on every page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
<HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path={"/"} component={Home} />
          <Route path={"/component"} component={AnotherComp} />
          <Route path={"*"} component={NotFound} />
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
```

Basically I have this code. and what I want is that when you go to just `/` it will render the home page but then adding a path will go to that page. However, I have 2 problems. Firstly, for some reason the home page is rendered on every page but with the content of the path page too. so `/` gives me home (this is correct). `/component` renders the AnotherComp component AND the home page. I just want it to render the single component. Another problem is that my `*` route is also rendering on all pages.
how can I get it so home only renders on `/`, and `*` only renders when the path is not known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `exact` to the route.

```
<Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
```

If you want a route that gets a hit on any unknown url you can use a switch statement.

```
<HashRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={"/"} component={Home} />
            <Route exact path={"/component"} component={AnotherComp} />
            <Route path={"*"} component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: ok this solves the home problem. but do you have any guidance for the not found component being rendered on every page?

Comment: note that you have to import the switch from 'react-router-dom'. `import {  HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';`